# How do I access content earlier added by :before selector using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Consider [this](http://codepen.io/labeeb/pen/bZXwOm) example.

I have a div and before it I added some content using `:before` in css. Now I want to access content(which is "some text before div ") I have added using jquery.

How can I do that?

html:

```
<div>A div</div>
```

css:

```
div:before{
  content:"some text before div ";

}
```

Comment: Define "*access*"

Comment: @Amit I want to be able to change its style

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a#change-text').click(function() {
  $("div:contains('A div')").toggleClass('v2');
});
```

```css
a#change-text {
  color: #00f;
}
div:before {
  content: "some text before div ";
}
div.v2:before {
  content: "text was changed ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>A div</div>
<a id="change-text">Change text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function init() {
    document.getElementById("foo")
            .addEventListener("click", 
     function() {
            document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule[0];
            document.styleSheets[0].addRule('div:before','content: "some other text?"');
     }, false);
}
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
```

```css
div:before{
  content:"some text before div ";
}
```

```html
<body>
<input id="foo" type="button">
<div>[<-- div -->]</div>
</body>
```